# Kingo Root issue

Tags: rooting, lock-screens, kingo

My android device is 4.4.2. I rooted my device with Kingo Root with PC.
Without any error message, it was successful.

However, after rooting Screen Lock is not working properly. Sometimes screen lock works and sometimes it doesn’t work.

I removed root access and reset my device. Then Screen Lock is working fine. Again after rooting, Screen Lock is not working fine.

I have been using Kingo Root with PC for long time. And depending upon scenario, I removed root access, reset device and re-root device. I never had any issue with it. Now I am facing Screen Lock issue.

Please let me know, how to fix it?

Regards

InTech

Comment: what do you mean by screen lock not working properly?

Comment: I tried I these locks; Swipe, Pattern & Password; after rooting. Screen goes OFF but it’s not locked. And sometimes without asking for pattern, swipe or password, it gets unlocked.

Comment: check whether problem continues with other rooting methods

Comment: I prefer rooting with PC only. And if I try other apps for rooting with PC, generally there is (are) some limitation(s)/issue(s) in that app. For example, in case of King Root, it appears with other language (not in English). That’s why I don’t prefer to use it. Kingo Root was working fine from beginning with my device. Now it’s creating problem so please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: I tried other apps like farmaroot, z4root, TunesGo Root etc (with PC and Without PC). In almost all cases, there are some issues/errors in rooting process. Also in some apps, language is not English that’s why I didn’t prefer to proceed. TunesGo Root is paid app. Only Kingo Root with PC and Kingo Root without PC can root my device successfully. But after rooting device, I see same issue i.e. screen lock issue.

Comment: Please let me brief my scenario. I prefer rooting with PC and I tried some apps like iRoot, King Root, Kingo Root, vRoot. In my case, except Kingo Root, almost all apps are detected as Trojan and Malware by Eset Internet Security installed in my computer, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Mobile and Kaspersky Internet Security for Android. Therefore, according to Eset Internet Security 10, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Mobile and Kaspersky Internet Security for Android; no need to worry with Kingo Root.

Comment: My device couldn’t be rooted with Farmaroot. Also no Custom Recovery and Custom ROM are compatible to my device. Therefore, only Kingo Root is suitable with my device. However I have an issue with Kingo Root. Even after successful rooting process, Screen Lock issue occurs in my device after rooting. From beginning, I have been using Kingo Root and earlier there was no such issue with Kingo Root.

Comment: To resolve this issue, I have gone through a series of steps. I removed Kingo Root access. Then Screen Lock issue resolved. Then I rooted by both ways; Kingo One-Click and Kingo with PC. Again same issue occurred in both cases. I re-flashed Stock ROM. Then rooted by both ways; Kingo One-Click and Kingo with PC. And again same issue occurred. Therefore, please help me to fix Kingo Root issue.